# Simplest way to repeat matrix along 3rd dimension

Tags: r

How to repeat a matrix `A` along 3rd dimension `n` times? `array(rep(A,n),c(dim(A),n))` should work but is there a simpler way? I was hoping `A[,,rep(1,n)]` would do the trick but apparently not.

Comment: Your method looks pretty simple to me.

Comment: btw, `array(A, c(dim(A), n))` seems sufficient too, since `array` recycles its argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the following is a little shorter:

```
myArray <- replicate(n, A)
```

Here is an example:

```
temp <- matrix(1:10, 5)
replicate(3, temp)
```

Comment: Super clean! Avoids the need to change dimensions as well

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to change the dimensions first:

```
A = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
dim(A) = c(dim(A), 1)

A[, , rep(1, 3)]
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```